# How to structure a big Angular library

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-packagr

I am creating a very big Angular library.
Because I have many classes and components, I have structured them in a hierarchy.
For example, I have:

- Map

  - Panels

    - Toolbar
    - MainPanel
    - Etc.
  - Layers

    - BingLayer
    - WMSLayer
    - WMTSLayer
  - Geometries

    - Point
    - Line
    - Polygon
      etc.

In the `public_api.ts`, I have many exports, one for each `component/module/service` I want to expose on the library, but this flattens my hierarchy.

The only way I found to maintain the hierarchy is to create a library for each group on the hierarchy tree. For example, a library for Panels (Panels-lib), a library for Layers (Layers-lib) etc. and then replicate the hierarchy on the file system putting each library in a separated folder: a folder for Panels, a folder for Layers etc.

In this way, in the main application I can import components in this way:

```js
import {ToolBar} from "MyMap/Panels/Panels-lib";
import {Line} from "MyMap/Geometries/Geometries-lib";
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this article can help https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/improve-spa-performance-by-splitting-your-angular-libraries-in-multiple-chunks-8c68103692d0

Here is how you can setup your library exports in the most efficient way with multiple entry points:

[image]

Also checkout how they structuring the [Angular Material components repo](https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/material), as a reference.